# Looking for an app to name colors on Mac (colorblind)?

Tags: software-recommendation, ms-office, color, accessibility

I am colorblind. I am looking for an app to help me identify colors by their basic names (blue, green, ...) when I am working on powerpoint or excel on mac (OSX 10.12).

On windows, I was using [whatcolor](http://www.hikarun.com/e/) quite successfully. This app translates the RGB code of the pixel under your mouse into intelligible color names such as blue, green, ... it's a real time-saver when you have to create powerpoints or excel.

I could not find anything similar so far on mac. I tried apps such as Visolve or Sim Daltonism but they did not have this simple functionality.

Please note I am not looking for a color picker such as DigitalColor Meter, that would just read out color RGB codes from pixels. I need a tool that "names" colors, stay on top of screen, with a compact window, just like whatcolor.

Comment: @patrix, This question is not a duplicate of the one you suggested for the simple fact that he is asking for an app that has the functionality of [WhatColor](http://www.hikarun.com/e/) so as to get the **Name** of the color, not a numeric value and none of the apps in the answers to the so called duplicate provide the color by name. That said, aren't software recommendations off-topic anyway? That's what Google is for and if you can't find it googling then it probably does exist.

Comment: I know this is not what you're looking for however it's the only thing I found googling that can give a **color name**, although you have to enter the numeric values. Have a look at: [Color Name & Hue](http://www.color-blindness.com/color-name-hue/) One alternative is to run a Windows VM to use WhatColor and do the related work in Windows.

Comment: @user3439894 See http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation for how software recommendation can be on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 apps on mac that name colors to help people with color blindness:

- A free app called [ColorCompass](http://www.color-compass.com/). It basically does the same job as WhatColor, although with a more simple color naming system. It's small, has instant color naming and stay on top of other windows.
- Also a free app called [ColorQuest](https://itunes.apple.com/app/colorquest/id807814068?mt=12). But this app takes more screen space and is quite slow. I did not find a way to make it stay on top, a deal breaker for me.

As a background, I am colorblind too and I personally use ColorCompass on my Mac to work with Mac Office all day long on a daily basis.